# How to access the XMLHttpRequest.send(string) value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xmlhttprequest

If I make a POST via a `XMLHttpRequest.send()`

I can add data to the send, eg: `XMLHttpRequest.send("Hello World")`

But I can't figure out how I can then get at the data I've placed in my send command in vb.net - I thought it could be accessed in the `HttpContext.Current.Request` object in my web application.  There must be a way to do it otherwise why would you be able to set it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data using a stream reader on the `InputStream` property

```
Using reader = New StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
    dim content = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: Ok I'm being dumb here, I don't see the connection between "my-setting" and the call I'm making.  If I try and access `HttpContext.Current("my-setting")` I get Class 'System.Web.HttpContext' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Comment: My bad ... typo. I've fixed it up.

Comment: Still not seeing the connection of the name "my-setting", if I check that property it returns Nothing.

Comment: Apologies for my first attempt. I thought you we're trying to access variables no the raw stream itself.

Comment: No worries. Ok got your code running but content = "" when I run it.  I've checked that my test javascript is making the .send request with some data in it.